# Blob url doesn't exsists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

### Blob link is created, but the link returns 404 error

About this code; I am making markdown text editor, and am working on copy/paste image functionality, such as from screenshot. When paste action is made, this code should console.log blob url of a pasted image. But it looks like image doesn't exsists when I go to blob link.

What I did wrong for passing the image as blob?

### code

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import { ReactMarkdown } from 'react-markdown/lib/react-markdown'

export default function Home() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

const handlePaste = async(e) => {
  var items = e.clipboardData.items;
  let image = [].slice.call(items).filter((obj)=> {
    // Filter the image items only
    return obj.type.indexOf('image') !== -1;
  })
    const item = image[0];
    console.log(item)
    
    // Get the blob of image
    const blob = await item.getAsFile();
    let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log(blobURL)

};

  return (
    <>
      <textarea 
      name="" 
      id="" 
      cols="30" 
      rows="10"
      value={input}
      onPaste={handlePaste}
      onChange={(e)=>setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <ReactMarkdown childrenhow ={input}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "go to the link". You can access the blob as a File object, and you can use the object URL as e.g. the `src` attribute of an `img` tag within the same document. But the object URL stops referring to anything as soon as you leave the page.